# Erlang - How to run more than one node on single windows vista machine?

Tags: erlang

i m graduate student and as my project i have to run Erlang Chat Application, but i am confused to run 2 nodes on my single machine having windows vista. can anybody help me please to run the application.

regards
anum

Comment: What about reading some introduction tutorials on Erlang first?

Answer (score 3):

In one window run

```
c:\program files\erl5.7.1\bin\werl -sname x
```

and in another run

```
c:\program files\erl5.7.1\bin\werl -sname y
```

Check for the exact path to your Erlang system. This will give you two Erlangs running in separate windows on the same machine. As you are running them from the same user there should be no problems with authentication. Check the links in @Roberto's answer for more information and details of what is going on and how to get them to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html)'s an introduction to Distributed Erlang.

[Here](http://www.erlang.org/examples/win95demo/win95demo.html)'s an example where it's explained how to start two Erlang nodes on the same LAN.